# Can messages in the App Store Resolution Center cause the reviewer to approve the app after rejection?

Tags: iphone, store, center, resolution

So my app was rejected because there is a part of the app that's not functioning until January but I allow the user to get a notification when the tools are available (they said this is a beta app which I explained we won't have all the data until January).  If I posted this note in the Resolution Center will they read and possibly review or do I need to resubmit a binary just to get them to read it?

Comment: Hey @krut. If the reviewer had an oversight your communication could turn things around but reviewers probably follow a manual so if your app clearly violates their policy in any way, anything you say will not change their decision... And just a heads up, Since this question is non-programming related it might be moved.

Comment: Sounds like a great question for the [AppStores stackexchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores?referrer=jcBbxTFsYbhSPTdluUKgFA2). Which unfortunately doesn't exist yet. But if you click on the link and commit that'll change ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can happen. I have first-hand experience of an app getting approved after initial rejection. This was by email, though, because the Resolution Center did not exist yet. I expect the same procedure still works though.

Comment: Hey, @Steven Kramer!  I asked too early!  I just got the approval!  Thanks.  :)